# What's a good macro recorder for Windows?

Tags: windows, automation, macros, user-interface

I'm looking for a tool that can record everything I do with my mouse/keyboard and playback recorded sessions. I've found some softwares that can replay macro using a script but none that can also record a session.

I remember that my old 'mac classic' was able to do that 20 years ago. Can't I do that now?

The solution should be free and support Windows XP.

Many thanks.

Comment: There is an excellent macro recorder from Pulover, that is free, fully GUI run, easy to use, configurable, and best of all, captures the recorded macros in the AHK (autohotkey) language so that they can, if desired, be integrated later into an autohotkey script.  You can find it here: http://www.macrocreator.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this one: http://www.macro-recorder.com/

It's also working on Windows 7!

Comment: That's exactly what I need.

Comment: It's not a freebie. It costs US$29.

Comment: Wow, what an ugly site! Looks like it has been designed last century... (Close, I see a 2004 copyright!)

Answer (score 13):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) has a very good macro recorder available as a helpful tool with it, namely AutoScriptWriter.

There is a menu item for it, but if you can't find it look in the installation folder. The recorded macros may need some improvement by hand, but are a very good start.

Comment: AHK is the solution to everyone's problem!

Comment: well, the script language is powerful, but the macro recording is not !

Comment: May not be the best macro recorder but nice and powerful for automating tasks in Windows

Comment: Indeed, it's a good one. But I was looking for a recorder that can start a record session and replay it. I don't want to create my macro by hand

Comment: I'm downvoting this for the same reason mentioned above. I use AHK a lot (and love it!), however it's not good for very simple one time use macros. Throw away macros should take seconds to make while AHK requires minutes.

Comment: @Annan: There are helpful tools for recording macros with AHK.

Comment: @harrymc: helpful tools such as?  Please do elaborate in your answer since as it currently is stated, it's false: AHK does *not* have macro *recorder* capabilities.  So I'm inclined to agree with Annan.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: AHK comes with AutoScriptWriter. There is a menu item for it, but if you can't find it look in the installation folder. The recorded macros may need some improvement by hand, but are a very good start.

Comment: @harrymc: Have you seen Pulover's Macro Creator?  That is a standalone program, fully GUI based, automatable, records, and best of all, captures the recorded macros in the AHK language which can be exported for use within AHK.  I think this is probably the better option.  Check it out here http://superuser.com/a/420824/153054  and here:  http://www.macrocreator.com/download/

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: Whichever one works for you is the best. I think I once tested Pulover's and it failed in my case.

Answer (score 6):

The best commercial one we tried is [Jitbit Macro Recorder](http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/). It can even compile macros to EXE files.

Also, there's a comparison article over at Wikipedia: [Comparison of macro recorder software](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20151127201520/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_macro_recorder_software)

Comment: But interestingly, Jitbit and AutoMacroRecorder are not on the Wikipedia list --- suspect the list is in its earliest stages of being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Early versions of Windows included a free macro recorder, but this seemed to be unstable if used on later editions.

About five years ago we had considerable success with MacroScheduler from MJTnet. This will enable you to record sessions, and also allow you to edit the session as a script - great for optimizing and tweaking a recorded macro.

Unfortunately it isn't free, but for our purposes we considered it excellent value for money. There is a trial version available. See: http://www.mjtnet.com/macro_scheduler.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Macro Express](http://www.macroexpress.com/index.htm) for years and would be lost without it. It is not free though.

Answer (score 0):

**Eventcorder** is a good one, but I can't get it to work on Vista, but it works fine on WinXP. It's functionality is like Jitbit. I think version 2.0.44 is still free.

Answer (score -7):

If you already have MS-Office there's a macro recorder built in.  I'm not sure how much it works with things outside the Office world though.

Comment: I need a system wide macro recorder