# How can I record macros for Autohotkey?

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I used a macro recorder for [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) in the past, but now I can't seem to find it at all.

**How can I record macros for Autohotkey?**

Comment: Why was this question closed? It doesn't seem to be off-topic here.

Comment: It doesn't demonstrate any research. I'd guess that a quick search would show some macro recorders or AHK documentation that would answer the question. There's nothing broken here, just someone asking someone else to do a web search on their behalf.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the original archive is gone after [AutoHotkey moved to GitHub](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey).
>
> However we are lucky that archive.org still has a copy:
> https://web.archive.org/web/20150908182356/http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip
>
> There also once was an alternative named Macrorecorder.com, but this page now is flagged by Mozilla/Google as being taken over by malware.

Unfortunately John T's answer is only half of the solution.  `AutoScriptWriter` is no longer a part of the newest AHK Installer.  It is only part of the full old version of AHK, called by the somewhat misleading name "AutoHotkey Basic".

- <strike>Go to the download page http://www.autohotkey.com/download/</strike>
- <strike>Find "Installer for AutoHotkey Basic"</strike>
- <strike>If you do not need UniCode, you can install this one, it includes `AutoScriptWriter`.  However I recommend to use the new AHK, so this is not the solution.</strike>
- Instead I recommend that you "download this zip file instead", at [http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908182356/http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip)
- In this ZIP there is a directory called `AutoScriptWriter`
- Copy this complete directory somewhere, including the DLL.
- You can run `AutoScriptWriter.exe` from within this directory.

Note that AutoScriptWriter does not create Unicode documents, so the `Save` button is useless now.  However you can use the Clipboard to copy the text portions you want.

This solution works for me as of 2011-10-25

Comment: The zip url download link not available any more.

Comment: Thank you for the note.  I updated my answer.  Thanks to wayback.archive.org there still is a copy left: https://web.archive.org/web/20150908182356/http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip

Answer (score 54):

I'm working on a new Macro Recorder for AutoHotkey. It has many features, you can edit any part of the macro, test it and easily create Scripts with Hotkeys or Hotstrings. If anyone's looking for a Free Macro Utility, please check it out.
[Pulover's Macro Creator](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=85452).

[GitHub download link](https://github.com/Pulover/PuloversMacroCreator/releases/latest)

[image]

Comment: (+1) - with donation.  Thanks for your brilliant work on the Macro Recorder.  I was looking for something like this, came across yours, and in a few minutes was able to automate something that would have taken a few hours of tedious effort.  Best part is that it was easy to figure out without reading any tutorials -- just a little trial and error.  Thanks.

Comment: I will love to try Pulover's Macro Creator once it pass Totalvirus site
shows 2 Trojans are embedded check : https://www.virustotal.com

Comment: Seconding what user391292 said, and downvoting.

Comment: < "C:\Program Files\MacroCreator\MacroCreator.exe" **is clean** now
[virustotal.com scan of this version](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/edc786206c7e57130740eb58d554d697697e251cde1bb578eb97c9caa112aded/analysis/)

Comment: This website is now in `security warning list` when opened in Chrome browser.

Comment: same goes for Firefox, and the site is actually quite empty - the Github repo is available though: https://github.com/Pulover/PuloversMacroCreator

Comment: Needs a new link in the answer

Comment: Also is a security warning in Firefox

Comment: This software is open source; you can build it yourself quite easily.  There will of course be false positives by heuristics-based virus scanners due to the nature of the program.  BTW I see no warning for the site in Chrome right now.

Comment: Avast also flags as warning, and collected the file for scanning. Will come here later to update the findings.

Comment: The file is clean. I am gonna use it now!

Comment: The installer from github contains the bloatware `AdAware` - watch out during installation if you don't want to install that and press decline on the right page.

Answer (score 12):

It comes with old versions of the [AutoHotkey installer](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.0/AutoHotkey104805.zip), it was called AutoScriptWriter.  Some discussion around it can be found at [the forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=70679).

[image]

Comment: can you please remove your answer? its 2016 we cant find that writer in there official site anymore.

Comment: @YumYumYum Why the heck a person should remove an answer? They put a time into it. Imagine removing books from the history. What the heck is that a request?!

Comment: @YumYumYum It's still at the official site, in older versions.  
https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.0/
https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.0/AutoHotkey104805.zip
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=70679

Comment: @Faither completely agree with you. Its asif all records of an old treasure are requested to be deleted from the history books and the internet, just because someone stole the treasure or because it was lost after a hurricane damaged a ship that sank to the bottom of the sea. The problem is that stuff (programs/information) is removed, not because there is too much of (programs/information) online.

Comment: 2 minutes of search: https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.0/AutoHotkey104805.zip from https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=306015&sid=ed7b1f0fbb964d246650f9492699fcff#p306015

Answer (score 12):

You have a couple of options:
[AutoScriptWriter.exe (from Autohotkey Basic)](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip)
[Recorder by Titan v0.11a (from user polyethene)](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21866-macro-recorder/)
[Pulover's Macro Creator 3.1](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/79763-macro-creator-v31-automation-tool-recorder-writer/)
[X-Macro Recorder v2.0.2](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/49096-x-macro-recorder-v202-automationmacro-tool/)
[Instant Text Automator - Instant 'Send'-based macros](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/63056-instant-text-automator-instant-send-based-macros/page__hl__macro+recorder)
[AHK MouseRecorder (from user garath)](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15118-ahk-mouserecorder-more/)

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/49096-x-macro-recorder-v202-automationmacro-tool/