# How to record keystrokes and/pr mouse clicks with AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, macros, autohotkey

It is claimed, that [AutoHotKey can record with macro recorder](http://ahkscript.org/). Unfortunately, I can't find any word about it in manual. Serfing leads to [Pulover's Macro Creator](http://www.macrocreator.com/).

Is this what it claimed in AHK page -- using this separate tool? Or AHK has it's own capabilities to record?

Comment: AutoHotkey definitely does not have built-in recording capabilities--you would need to use a third party macro recorder if you don't want to just code the macro from scratch.  I have never used Pulover's Macro Creator but it looks like a good tool to use if you want to automate some of the coding.

Comment: dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/229720/how-can-i-record-macros-for-autohotkey

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotKey *did* once provide a macro recorder called AutoScriptWriter, but it was dropped quite some time ago. You will need to use a third-party tool to record AHK macros.

Comment: Not a super helpful "answer" --one or more links to the tantalizing solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

See the good answer for [How can I record macros for Autohotkey?](https://superuser.com/questions/229720/how-can-i-record-macros-for-autohotkey)

TL/DR: https://github.com/Pulover/PuloversMacroCreator/releases